# Eclipse.exe is not starting, also I've deleted .m2 folder, workbench4, and workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, scala

Tried to download all the dependent java versions and scala jdk for it and tried to edit the configuration `.ini` file but when clicking upon `eclipse.exe` it's trying to load for a second and nothing opening every time clicking on it.

.ini file

Comment: Could you start it with your terminal and show which kind of error occurs on start-up?

Comment: I suspect something is wrong in the `eclipse.ini` file. You'd better reset it by getting a clean, new `ini` file. And then, do whatever modifications you will until it crashes. (Take special care of the path contained in the `-jvm` parameter , if there is one.)